# Run the HTML5 Ant Build Script on a server

Tags: ant, build-automation, html5boilerplate

The HTML5 Ant Build Script seems to be primarily a front end tool - https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script

But does anyone know if it's possible to run the build script on a server? Reason for this is that there are three of us on our team and it makes more sense for the script to be run automatically when someone has pushed to the server via git rather than all three of us running the script locally.

I may be a million miles off with this but is someone able to offer a good solution for us not having to run the script individually?